# Azure Pipelines doesn't compile my repository code, just clones it

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment

I've a application built with ASP.NET, and would like to integrate  Virtual Machine with CI/CD service of Azure DevOps. I'm sure that Web Deploy is installed in VM, Agent Pool is configurated and Azure Pipelines is "linked" with Agent Pool and Github repository. But when i execute the Pipeline, it don't generate any error ,however instead of compile or publish the code,  it simply clone which is in repository and copy to `_work/1/s` inside VM. Could someone help me?

Comment: Need to see more of your pipeline YAML or screenshot of the tasks for classic.  I would guess you haven't defined any tasks to do the actual compilation.

Comment: @Matt I used the "wizard" mode of pipeline to configure without YAML, using GUI os Azure Pipeline

Comment: Take a screenshot of your tasks under "Agent job 1".  You should have at least one "visual studio build" task.  If you don't have that, you probably aren't compiling.  You could also add snippets from the output log.

Comment: I may be wrong but it is hard to believe that `it don't generate any error`. It should be in the logs.

Comment: We need your pipeline definition to help you. Can you share it with us?

Comment: Hi, is there any update for this issue? Feel free to let me know whether my anwser helps.

Answer (score 1):

There are probably no corresponding tasks for compiling or publishing in your pipeline.

As you are building a ASP.NET application and using Classic UI pipeline, you can apply ASP.NET template:

[image]

In the template:

The 'Build solution' task is for building and 'Publish Artifact' task is for publishing.

If you want to know detailed information of a task, click it and choose 'More Information'. It will link you to the document for the task.

[image]

To learn more about build and release tasks, you can read [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/?view=azure-devops).